# Is there a way to add a tooltip to the rating component on Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I am trying to add a tooltip to each star of the rating component on Material UI [v4] but I am not being able to.

Is there a way to achieve this without having to use another rating library?

These are the links for the components I am trying to implement:

https://material-ui.com/es/api/rating/
https://material-ui.com/es/api/tooltip/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the solution of @hamidreza which was similar to the one posted [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/20279) but it did not work for me.

I know I'm a bit late to this but here is my solution:

Enclosing the `<Rating>` component with `<Box>` or a `div` (due to multiple child errors from Tooltip) then placing it as a child of the `<Tooltip>` component.

```
const [value, setVal] = React.useState(2);
const [tipValue, setTipValue] = React.useState(2);

<Tooltip title={tipValue === -1 ? value : tipValue}>
  <Box display="inline-block">
    <Rating
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setVal(newValue);
      }}
      onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
        setTipValue(newHover);
      }}
    />
  </Box>
</Tooltip>
```

Working Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-haze-jlvbb8?file=/demo.tsx

Splitting the `tipValue` and the `value` for me was necessary. This is to change the Tooltip message on hovering on the Rating component.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a custom `IconContainerComponent` and create your own `Tooltip` inside.

```
<Rating
  IconContainerComponent = {
    function IconContainer(props) {
      // trigger your custom tooltip here
      const { value, ...other } = props;
      return <span {...other} />;
    }
  }
/>
```